# How to use MinGW to generate .lib and .dll files in Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw32

I want to generate static and dynamic link libraries for Windows, using CMake to build, specifying MinGW as the generator. But the generated file name suffix is `.a`. Isn't this a static link library for Linux? How should I set it to obtain a static link library with `.lib` as the suffix?

Comment: MinGW uses .a for static libraries. .lib is for MSVC.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20200201112153/http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL

Comment: @possum Not what the OP wants, I fancy (but a useful link nonetheless)

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm confused.  The question asks "How to use MinGW to generate .lib and .dll files in Windows" and I linked to "HOWTO Create and Deploy a Sample DLL using MinGW".  Am I missing something?

Comment: ***How should I set it to obtain a static link library with .lib as the suffix?*** Is your code `c` or `c++`? If you are using `c++` and want a `.lib` then you likely need to use msvc. Remember that `c` code will be generally compatible between MinGW and msvc but `c++` code will not be compatible in most cases.

Comment: @possum OP wants to build a static .lib also, I believe (which might not be possible with MinGW, IDK)